# Ember.js Route.setupController with ObjectController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm puzzled why how the `Route` and `Controller` are affecting the default `Model`. Here is an example.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        console.log(model); //returns undefined
        controller.set("title", "Page title");
    }
});
```

This code snippet above **works** without errors; the template prints `{{title}}` as expected. Note that the model is "undefined."

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        console.log(model); //returns undefined
        controller.set("title", "Page title");
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

The code immediately above **throws an error** ...

> (Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate
>   set('title', Page title) to the 'content' property of object proxy
>   : its 'content' is undefined.)

... and yields a blank page. The solution is to return a model (blank object) or use a `Controller` (default behavior) instead of an `ObjectController`. Could someone explain this peculiar circumstance? Why doesn't Ember assume an empty object when using an `ObjectController`? Is it assuming the object will be passed in or retrieved from the store or server?

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {};
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        console.log(model);
        controller.set("title", "Page title");
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html):

> Ember.ObjectController is part of Ember's Controller layer. It is
>   intended to wrap a single object, proxying unhandled attempts to get
>   and set to the underlying model object, and to forward unhandled
>   action attempts to its target.

ObjectController expects a model is present and it is set as the content. It is basically a wrapper around the single object.